# The JavaScript language has encountered an error and has been shut down. (Tried Suggested links)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Since updating Visual Studio 2013, (Update 2) I keep receiving this error message:

[image]

```
The JavaScript language has encountered an error and has been shut down. Please save your changes, exit, and restart Visual Studio.
```

This error occurs on old and new projects, and researching into it i dont seem to be getting anywhere. I have tried the obvious (stated in the error message) but this occurs each time i load up a javascript window. I insalled app builder shortly after (Telerik) which also may have caused an issue, im still looking at it myself but would appreciate any suggestions

cheers for any help

Comment: Do you use Resharper or Web Essentials 2013, perhaps?

Comment: i have them both :) Visual Studio had a corrupt file, unfortunately had no option but to remove it all and re-install

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not the best answer but it worked for me... I had to completely remove Visual Studio 2013 (along with the Visual Studio 2013 folder in Documents) and reinstall it.

uninstalled Visual Studio 2013 Update 2, and installed Visual Studio 2013 Update 4.

Hope this helps anyone in need of it. but please note that uninstalling and re-installing this software takes around 2-3 hours on some machines

Answer (score 1):

I installed Visual Studio 2015 today and i faced also same error. My previous project on VS 2010. Then I run my project on Vs 2015. Then i opened JS page. It took long time and gave same error. Then I took new JS page from add new Item and paste all the code of old JS file. then i saved it, and previous js file, i have deleted. then i saved the project and exit, then again open the project. and open Js file so there is no error now.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem when I was replacing the reference ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.13.1.js to the newer ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js.

Just after including the newer reference (before excluding the older), I got this message and lost all Intellisense for the .js files.

Returned to the older reference to get rid of the error.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for future problems, thanks for the suggestion