# VS2015 JavaScript language service has encountered an error and has been shut down

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I ran into this issue and it refuses to go away.  Error popsup every time I load any project/solution.  I tried some solutions for [VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26839472/the-javascript-language-has-encountered-an-error-and-has-been-shut-down-tried) but those didn't work for VS 2015.  I have update3 and .net core installed.  I've tried uninstalling all that but issue remains.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few other links to SO that don't work.

Near as I can tell because I've customized an ad blocker in Chrome and I do debugging in other Chrome windows by attaching to those processes that this *might* cause it but that's not proven.

However, if I've been to Fox News, which is what I have the .js snippet for and I've left the Chrome Tools window open, this error does occur.

I've saved the .js file, removed the folder from Chrome to see if this will handle it.